# If $−1<x<4$ then determine $a$ and $b$ in $a<2x+3<b$.

Tags: inequality

In this problem:
"If $−1 < x < 4$ then determine $a$ and $b$ in $a < 2x + 3 < b$"
I solved it like this:
$-1 < x < 4$,
Interval notation for $x$: $(-1, 4)$
$a < 2x + 3 < b$,
$a < (-1 * 2, 4 * 2 ) + 3 < b$,
$a < (-2, 8) + 3 < b$, then $a < (1, 11) < b$
$a < (1, 11)$, Interval notation for $a$: $(-∞, 1]$
$(1, 11) < b$, Interval notation for $b$: $[11, ∞)$
But in my learning material, I found the answer:
$-1 < x < 4$,
$−2 < 2x < 8$,
$1 < 2x+3 < 11$, and since $a < 2x + 3 < b$,
Then, $a = 1$ and $b = 11$.
Did I do something wrong? Or is the answer specified in the material wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did do something wrong: abuse notation without understanding what is based on, and misinterpreting the result that should be obtained.

$a$ is **in** the interval $(-\infty,1]$ but that doesn't mean it **is** the interval.

It is a singular value for which the statement $a<2x+3$ must always be true, given the knowledge $-1<x$. One could ask why not simply answer that $a=-\infty$, since that would always be true, but it would also be trivial and pointless to discuss in this case.